# Need 64 bit jdk 1.5 for windows

Tags: java

I need a 64bit version of jdk 1.5 installer for windows 7. I am unable to find anywhere. What i could see was a AMD version of 64 bit jdk1.5 for windows. Will this work? or suggest a site where I can get the older verions of jdk. I saw the [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase5-419410.html#jre-1.5.0-oth-JPR) but its not giving me 64 bit version.

Comment: Have you tried to download the 'AMD' version and run it... It will work...Its what I'm running on Windows 7

Comment: *"I need a 64bit version of jdk 1.5 installer for windows 7."*  You almost certainly don't.  1) The 32 & 64 bit JDKs will both compile code down to the exact same binary. 2) If you need the code to be compatible with 1.5+, use the cross-compilation options (and a 1.5 `rt.jar`).

Comment: @radimpe, am tyring this now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AMD64 means 64-bit, including Intel (except IA-64, found on some servers).

Seriously though, 1.5 went EOL a long time ago. Time to upgrade!

Comment: Thanks @artbistol. I need this for the latest version of STS to install. The latest version of STS isn't working with jdk7 (which i have on my machine).

Comment: How about 1.6? It's still relatively current.

Comment: i tried it. Only 1.5 is needed :-(

Comment: STS as in Springsource Tool Suite?

Comment: Just installed STS 2.9.1.  Works nicely with JDK 1.6.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, for me STS [64 bit] is not working properly with jdk1.6 & jdk7[32 bit]

Comment: Then download the 32-bit version?

Answer (score 1):

> Java Development Kit 5.0 Update 22, 33.12 MB, jdk-1_5_0_22-windows-amd64.exe

Sound like what you want? The link is there on that page you linked to!

I'll spare you my usual rant about how you / whoever is making you use Java 1.5 should really move on a couple of versions ;)

Comment: some platforms are slow movers.  On some IBM platforms the newest Java version you can rely on being available easily is 1.5.